# Placing two html buttons within a popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im currently trying to insert some custom HTML in a popover. Im simply trying to add the following HTML to the popover:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-large btn-succes" type="button">Button 2</button>
```

I've tried with the following setup of HTML:

```
<div id="voteSubText"
data-toggle="popover"
data-placement="top"
data-content="
<div><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Button 1</button></div>
<div><button class="btn btn-large btn-succes" type="button">Button 2</button></div>
"
title="title"
data-original-title="title">div text</div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#voteSubText').popover({ html : true });
```

However this is not working. Any suggestions on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Hi PSL - sorry for leaving you hanging - ive been away since posting. I'll just look at your very fine response in an hour and get some feedback your way! :)

Comment: No problem.. Hope it gives you what you need...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML itself is invalid. You cannot have html tags inside an attribute. You have added some html as is inside `data-content`.

Instead try like this:-

#### Html

```
<div id="voteSubText" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="title" data-original-title="title">eller</div>

<!--Add a separate section for buttons-->
<div class="buttons">
    <div>
        <button class=" btn btn-large btn-primary " type="button ">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-succes " type="button ">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$('#voteSubText').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('.buttons').html(), // Select the html from button
    trigger: 'click'
});
```

### Css

```
//Hide the buttons div which is in DOM.
.buttons {
    display:none;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/emdcn/)

Another option is instead of keeping Buttons in DOM.You can do it in the script. But according to me this makes it less maintainable.

```
var buttons='<div><button class=" btn btn-large btn-primary " type="button ">Button 1</button></div> <div><button class="btn btn-large btn-succes " type="button ">Button 2</button> </div>';

$('#voteSubText').popover({
    html: true,
    content: buttons,
    trigger: 'click'
});
```

Comment: Hi PSL - you example works perfectly - got it running locally here also. I guess its my own fault for explaning poorly - but my intended use was actually to have two circle buttons and clicking either would then do the popover under #voteSubText - so im actually not looking to click the "eller" text to make it show.

Updated a fiddle - not sure if you have any idea how to do in that context? http://jsfiddle.net/EjRTw/1/

Comment: I was babbling man - I got it all sorted out - thanks again for doing such a throughout example!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
///HTML with hyperlink
      <div id="btnSave_popover" class="div-popover">
        <div>
          <a id="btnSave">SAVE</a>
        </div>
        <div >
            <a id="btnTemplate" > TEMPLATE</a>
        </div>
      </div>


///Css classes for popover

        .div-popover {
            background-color: white;
            border-radius: 8px !important;
            box-shadow: -1px 1px 9px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 7px 10px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 250px;
            bottom: -4px;
        }

        .div-popover:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -10px;
            left: 175px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 25px 25px 0;
            border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
        }
        .hidden {
         display: none !important;
        }
///JQuery for button click 

$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    if ($("#btnSave_popover").hasClass("hidden")) {
        $("#btnSave_popover").removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $("#btnSave_popover").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```